# Java mail with + character in email address

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, mail-server

I'm using java mail to sent mail from my applcation, this is working for normal mail address those having alphanumberic in email part.

But if i try to sent mail to email addresses like in format

```
email+@domain.com
```

At this time mail is sending to `email@domain.com` ,not to `email+@domain.com`.

**Update:** Is there any way i can override the special meaning of + character(by pre-processing) in mail servers( like encoding ..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interpretation of the local part of an email address is up to the receiving mail server.  If the receiving server treats "email" and "email+" as meaning the same mailbox, there is nothing you ... or your local javamail library ... can do about that.

---

> Is there any way i can override the special meaning of + character in mail servers( like encoding ..)

No standard encoding or escaping mechanism is mentioned in the [Wikipedia article on email addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local_part), and I can't recall one.  (But feel free to research this yourself by reading the relevant RFCs.)

If there is such mechanism, it would be mail server specific.  Consult the relevant mail server documentation.

Comment: can i get any proof or link to this.. sorry i need to convince client :-)

Comment: You need to answer the client with reference to the documentation for the client's own mail server.  You could also show them a network packet dump of the SMTP session from javamail to the server in which the plus characters are present in the outgoing email addresses.

Comment: Also send the same message using using a different mail client and see that the message goes to the same place.

Comment: @BillShannon - yea.  That would be convincing too.  (But I guess that we are assuming that the client going to be logical about this ...)

Comment: Is there any way i can override the special meaning of + character in mail servers( like encoding ..)

Comment: Can you try using concatenation? try with  "email" + '+' + "@domain.com"

Comment: @RiponAlWasim - That is not what he is asking.  He is asking if there is a way to tell the mail server to treat the `+` as an "ordinary" character.  I've already answered that -- AFAIK, no.

Comment: I'm sorry to misunderstand the question